# Calculating the probability of events in subcommittees

Tags: probability

Suppose I have 27 people. 20 woman and 7 men.
I first select 9 people to form a committee. 
Then I take 4 people from the 9 to form a subcommittee.

Im interested in the probability of 1 man being in the subcommittee and would like to calculate it using combinations.
Should the number of ways in which the subcommittee can be formed be:
27C4 or 27C9 *9C4
I feel like it should be it should be 27C9 * 9C4 because it allows double counting of the same subcommittees selected from different committees.

ie, the same subcommittee of {M,M,W,W} can be formed from both {M,M,M,W,W,W,W,W,W} and {M,M,M,M,W,W,W,W,W}.

Thus {M,M,M,W,W,W,W,W,W}->{M,M,W,W} and {M,M,M,M,W,W,W,W,W}->{M,M,W,W} are actually 2 single events.

According to my textbook. we should be using 27C4 but what is wrong with my argument for 27C9 *9C4?

Comment: If we are interested in the sub committee having at least one man, why is it not $\binom{27}{4} - \binom{20}{4}$?

Comment: If you are dealing with probabilities involving the final subcommittee, it doesn't matter how it was form. What committee if came from. It only matters which 4 people are in it. Hence $27\choose4$

Comment: PS: is that *at least* one man, or *exactly* one man?

Comment: From the examples OP has given, it is *at least* one man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Choose}[2]{{^{#1}{\rm C}_{#2}}}$

> I feel like it should be it should be 27C9 * 9C4 because it allows double counting of the same subcommittees selected from different committees.

You are not *exactly* wrong.   $\Choose{27}{9}\Choose{9}{4}$ does indeed count the ways to select a committee of nine with four special places (the subcommittee); which is also equal to $\Choose{27}{4}\Choose{23}{5}$.

However, count of ways to select a committee of nine with four special places among which there is *exactly* one man is: $\Choose{7}{1} \Choose{20}{3} \Choose{23}{5}$.   So the last factor cancels and we might as well not bother.

(Similarly for the case of "... *at least* one man")

Answer (score 1):

You can simply forget about the larger committee, and find the complement of the $Pr$ that no man is on a directly chosen subcommittee of $4$, because first forming a committee and then forming a subcommittee in effect counts all ways of directly forming the subcommittee.

Thus $Pr = 1 - \dfrac{\binom{20}4}{\binom{27}4}$

Answer (score 0):

Exactly $1$ man:

$$\frac{\binom{7}{1}\cdot\binom{27-7}{4-1}}{\binom{27}{4}}$$

---

At least $1$ man:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{4}\frac{\binom{7}{n}\cdot\binom{27-7}{4-n}}{\binom{27}{4}}$$